# R ggRadar differences in behavior with interactive turned on or off

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make interactive radar graphs. The ggRadar (note the capital R in ggRadar; there is a different package called ggradar) package makes use of the interactive tools in ggiraph to do this.

If you run the code below, you get a nice looking radar chart. If you change to interactive = TRUE, then you get the error message

> Error in p + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 11,
>   family = "Times",  :    non-numeric argument to binary operator

```
    require(ggiraphExtra)
            spiderData <- data.frame(year = c("X2010", "X2020"), nut1 = c(2.87, 6.66),
     nut2 = c(445, 486), nut3 = c(176, 251), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
                            p <- ggRadar(data = spiderData[,1:ncol(spiderData)],
mapping = aes(colour = year), 
    rescale = FALSE, interactive = FALSE, use.label = TRUE, legend.position = "right")
            p <- p + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 11, family = "Times", 
                face = "plain")) + ggtitle("Title text")
             p
```

If you run just

```
ggRadar(data = spiderData[,1:ncol(spiderData)], mapping = aes(colour = year), 
             rescale = FALSE, interactive = TRUE, use.label = TRUE, legend.position = "right")
```

you get a nice interactive graph. I'd like to get an interactive graph where I can also add elements such as a title (and probably other things as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your interest in my package ggiraphExtra.
You can get interactive plot with ggiraph() function from ggiraph package.

require(ggiraph)
ggiraph(code=print(p))

Comment: The trick to this is to set interactive to FALSE in the original construction of the graph, store the graph in a variable (p in this instance), and then use `ggiraph(code = print(p))`